# FastAPI AssertionError: Cannot specify 'Depends' for <class 'starlette.requests.Request'>

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to use FastAPI with Depends and Annotations, but am getting AssertionError: Cannot specify 'Depends' for <class 'starlette.requests.Request'>.

fastapi==0.103.1

Example query

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Request, Response
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from ray import serve
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from typing_extensions import Annotated

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # do some lifespan stuff like loading configs

app = FastAPI(debug=True, lifespan=lifespan)
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allowed_origins=[...],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["GET", "POST"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)

@serve.deployment()
@serve.ingress(app)

class NewAPI:
@app.post("/login")
    async def login(
        user_email: [Annotated(str, Form()],
        request: Request,
        response: Response
    ):
        # do some processing to create a token
        return token

deployment = NewAPI.bind()
serve.run(deployment)
```

How should i address this error?
Use an older version?

Comment: It would be nice to see what you import

Comment: @BastienB updated the imports! Please help to take a look